# Ionic 4 + Stenciljs - adding support for google analytics

Tags: progressive-web-apps, ionic4, stenciljs

I am playing with an interesting set of frameworks Ionic and Stenciljs - I do not want to add anything more there (no angular, vue, etc.) and due to that I am facing some issues.

I am currently trying to understand how I can add google analytics to my application as well as how I can track additional actions with web-components (for example - ionic-radio changes, ionic-slides and actions there). I was hoping I can handle this via stencil-routing - but I can't without angular.

I am lost.

I can't find anything without angular - I believe the only option I can see is adding the js snippet from google - but can this be true?

Comment: So you're not using Cordova?

Comment: @Tachyon - nope. Ionic, Firebase and Stencil. Part of the exercise is to keep it as limited as possible :)

Comment: I think your best bet would then be to insert the JS script into your main `index.html` and let it pull through the stats from there. I know cordova has a plugin for Google analytics that supports the browser platform. Other than that I am unfortunately not sure.

Comment: @Tachyon - thank you. That was my understanding as well. I think that autotrack may be of help here - https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack

I will update this thread with results in few days (after some data and testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is simpler than expected. 
You do not need the additional framework- you can do this like that:

in your index.html file:

```
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
  //TODO: change to prod tracking ID!
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-X', 'auto');

  // Replace the following lines with the plugins you want to use.
  ga('require', 'eventTracker');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
  <script async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
  <script async src="/assets/js/autotrack.js"></script>
```

Then in every component, you need to track action you have to add few tags, my example:

```
<ion-button class="onboardin-action-button" slot="start" onClick={() => this.skipButtonClickHandler()} ga-on="click" ga-event-category="Onboarding" ga-event-action="skipped" >Skip </ion-button>
```

Where: 
ga-on --> actions we are tracking 
ga-event-category --> defined by us event category that will be visible in GA 
ga-event-action --> defined by us event action that will be visible in GA

Hope that will help someone :)